# I cant adjust the bottom sheet to the full screen

Tags: dart

I was doing a Bottom Sheet on flutter and it appears when you click on a marker but normally i set for being adjusted to the fullscreen but its not working. That's another file not the main.dart.
Im trying to simulate it as google maps because of a project
Even if i made the maxChildSize : 1.0 its not working its just stops on the half of the screen.
And with no idea it looks like there is two sheets at same time behind each other somehow
(I slid it a little bit to show you)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_polyline_points/flutter_polyline_points.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';


class HistoricPlacesPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HistoricPlacesPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override

  _HistoricPlacesPageState createState() => _HistoricPlacesPageState();
}

class _HistoricPlacesPageState extends State<HistoricPlacesPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Tarihi Mekanlar:'),
      ),
      body: const HistoricPlacesState(),
    );
  }
}

class HistoricPlacesState extends StatefulWidget {
  const HistoricPlacesState({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HistoricPlacesState createState() => _HistoricPlacesState();
}

class _HistoricPlacesState extends State<HistoricPlacesState> {
  GoogleMapController? mapController;
  PolylinePoints polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();

  String googleAPIKey = "AIzaSyAKH6d1oamW2_tEdGbNFdUe0Jv5XBUk2FA";

  Set<Marker> markers = {};
  Map<PolylineId, Polyline> polylines = {};

  LatLng startLocation = const LatLng(40.9987143, 39.6901263);
  LatLng endLocation = const LatLng(40.6166000, 39.7084000);
  LatLng homeLocation = const LatLng(40.8206762648865, 39.69222508441611);
  LatLng SumelaManastiri = const LatLng(40.690297475921405, 39.658346616861635);
  LatLng KiliseKalinti = const LatLng(40.790844518654914, 39.62655742442609);
  LatLng Yayla = const LatLng(40.66953558620199, 39.69439747044871);
  LatLng VManastiri = const LatLng(40.76198952431119, 39.53013865696186);
  LatLng KManastiri = const LatLng(40.80284530476671, 39.707192907232816);
  @override
  void initState() {

    markers.add(Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId(startLocation.toString()),
      position: startLocation,
      infoWindow: const InfoWindow(
        title: 'Anabasis Yolu',
        snippet: 'Başlangıç noktası',
      ),
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
    ));


    markers.add(Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId(KiliseKalinti.toString()),
      position: KiliseKalinti,
      infoWindow: const InfoWindow(
        title: 'Aya Yannis Kilise Kalıntısı',
        snippet: '',
      ),
      onTap: (){
    },
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueGreen),
    ));

    markers.add(Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId(VManastiri.toString()),
      position: VManastiri,
      infoWindow: const InfoWindow(
        title: 'Vazelon Manastırı',
        snippet: '',
      ),
      onTap: (){
      },
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueMagenta),
    ));

    markers.add(Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId(Yayla.toString()),
      position: Yayla,
      infoWindow: const InfoWindow(
        title: 'İskopel Yaylası',
        snippet: '',
      ),
      onTap: (){
      },
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueOrange),
    ));

    markers.add(Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId(SumelaManastiri.toString()),
      position: SumelaManastiri,
      infoWindow: const InfoWindow(
        title: 'Sümela Manastırı',
        snippet: '',
      ),
      onTap: () {
        showModalBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: DraggableScrollableSheet(
                initialChildSize: 1.0,
                maxChildSize: 1.0,
                minChildSize: 0.2,
                builder: (context, scrollController) {
                  return SingleChildScrollView(
                    controller: scrollController,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        AppBar(
                          title: const Text('Sümela Manastırı'),
                          automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                        const Text(
                          'Sümela Manastırı',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                        const Text(
                          'Buraya istediğiniz ek bilgileri ekleyebilirsiniz.',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueBlue),
    ));







    markers.add(Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId(KManastiri.toString()),
      position: KManastiri,
      infoWindow: const InfoWindow(
        title: 'Kuştul Manastırı',
        snippet: '',
      ),
      onTap: (){
      },
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueAzure),
    ));

    markers.add(Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId(endLocation.toString()),
      position: endLocation,
      infoWindow: const InfoWindow(
        title: 'Anabasis Yolu',
        snippet: 'Varış noktası',
      ),
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
    ));

    getDirections();

    super.initState();
  }

  getDirections() async {
    List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates = [];

    PolylineResult result = await polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
      googleAPIKey,
      PointLatLng(startLocation.latitude, startLocation.longitude),
      PointLatLng(endLocation.latitude, endLocation.longitude),
      travelMode: TravelMode.driving,
    );

    if (result.points.isNotEmpty) {
      result.points.forEach((PointLatLng point) {
        polylineCoordinates.add(LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude));
      });
    } else {
      print(result.errorMessage);
    }
    addPolyline(polylineCoordinates);
  }

  addPolyline(List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates) {
    PolylineId id = const PolylineId("poly");
    Polyline polyline = Polyline(
      polylineId: id,
      color: Colors.green,
      points: polylineCoordinates,
      width: 8,
    );
    polylines[id] = polyline;
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Stack(
      children: [
        GoogleMap(
          zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: homeLocation,
            zoom: 10.7,
          ),
          markers: markers,
          polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(polylines.values),
          mapType: MapType.hybrid,
          onMapCreated: (controller) {

            setState(() {
              mapController = controller;
            });
          },
        ),
      ],

    );
  }
}
```